# Bloquear teclado e mouse ou impedir usuario deixar janela em C#

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela de bloqueio estilo a de *lan-house* onde o usuário não sai da tela sem a permissão do servidor, gostaria de saber se tem como impedir o usuário de utilizar teclado e *mouse* ou de ele deixar o *Form* aberto (exemplo <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>), tem algumas funções da DLL *user32*, mas ela só funciona com privilégios de Administrador, e para mim fica inviável abrir a aplicação neste modo.

**Obs**: Já consegui bloquear o fechamento da tela via <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, e também já consegui impedir que o usuário abra o gerenciador de tarefas.

Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer uma aplicação que tenha total controle sob o PC sem ter um usuário Elevado?

Comment: Não controle total, mas impedir que o usuário da aplicação.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode-se utilizar a função [`BlockInput`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-blockinput), com ela você bloqueará o uso do teclado e *mouse*.

```c-sharp
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern void BlockInput([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool fBlockIt);
     
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    BlockInput(true); 
}
```

<sub>Exemplo retirado do [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/115480/C-BlockInput-mouse-and-keyboard).</sub>

Mas para usa-la, é necessário ter **privilégios** (a partir do Windows Vista), crie um [arquivo manifesto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests) e altere o elemento [`requestedExecutionLevel`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/deployment/trustinfo-element-clickonce-application?view=vs-2015) para:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Quando executar o programa, a janela do *UAC* vai aparecer para confirmar a execução do programa com privilégios.

Exemplo de um arquivo manifesto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
    xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
    xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication" />
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
                 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

### Alternativa

Uma **alternativa** é usar [*Hooks*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks) para interceptar os eventos do *mouse* e teclado e manipular o funcionamento destes.

Os artigos abaixo explicam o uso de *Hooks* No C#.

- [**Low-Level Keyboard Hook in C#**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217145327/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx)
- [**Low-Level Mouse Hook in C#**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316192051/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx)

Abaixo segue exemplos de como anular o funcionamento do *mouse* e teclado.

### **Mouse**

```c-sharp
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        // Importa as funções que serão usadas
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int code, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private enum MouseMessages{
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }

        const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14; // Tipo de hook que será usado

        private LowLevelMouseProc hook = hookProc;
        private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

        public void SetHook(){
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, hook, hInstance, 0); // Instala o hook para a interceptação dos eventos do mouse
        }

        public static void UnHook(){
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook); // Remove o hook instalado
        }

        public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam){
            // Se a mensagem recebida for > 0 e o clique do mouse for do botão esquerdo ou direito
            if (code >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam || MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                return (IntPtr)1; // Inibe o clique
            }
            else
                return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, (int)wParam, lParam); // Passa para o próximo evento
        }

        private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e){
            UnHook(); // Ao fechar o form desintalamos o hook
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
            SetHook(); // Ao iniciar instala o hook 
        }
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima é utilizado o *callback* [`LowLevelMouseProc`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29), o sistema chama essa função cada vez que um novo evento relacionado ao *Mouse* está para ser lançado na [*fila de mensagens*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fila_de_mensagens), quando interceptada, devolvemos um resultado diferente do esperado.

### **Teclado**

```c-sharp
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        // Importa as funções que serão usadas
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int code, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13; // Tipo de hook que será usado
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;  // Messagem usada para quando uma tecla for pressionada

        private LowLevelKeyboardProc hook = hookProc;
        private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

        public void SetHook(){
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hook, hInstance, 0); // Instala o hook para o teclado
        }

        public static void UnHook(){
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }

        public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam){
            if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN){ // Quando uma tecla for pressionada
                return (IntPtr)1; // Inibe o funcionamento
            }
            else
                return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, (int)wParam, lParam); // Passa para o próximo evento
        }

        private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            UnHook(); // Ao fechar o form desintala o hook
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetHook(); // Ao iniciar instala o hook
        }
    }
}
```

O exemplo acima não é válido para combinações de [**teclas especiais do sistema**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key) como o <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>. Aqui é usado o *callback* [`LowLevelKeyboardProc`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29), ela é chamada toda vez que um novo um novo evento de entrada do teclado está prestes a ser colocado na [*fila de mensagens*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fila_de_mensagens), ao interceptá-la podemos saber qual a tecla está a ser digitada, devolver outra tecla de retorno, ou anulá-la.

É importante sempre desinstalar o *gancho* após o uso com a função [`UnhookWindowsHookEx`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unhookwindowshookex).

Comment: Já tentei essa alternativa, e como eu disse antes, ela não funciona se não for executado como administrador no Windows 7 em diante.

Comment: Eu fiz exatamente como o colega ali em cima falou, até copie agora para testar novamente. Se eu executar como usuário comum o button1 não faz nada, já se eu clicar com botão direito e executar como administrador o button1 trava o teclado e mouse.

Comment: Consegui com Hooks, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @quark8 estava pesquisando métodos para o bloqueio do mouse e teclado e realmente ele estar os bloqueando, porém ele também para a execução do restante do programa. Há alguma forma de bloquear-los mas que o programa continue executando determinada função? Ou há algum outro procedimento que terá este mesmo efeito sendo que a aplicação continue executando as suas funções?

Comment: @JoaquimCaetanoTeixeira Não sei se seria adequado, mas já pensou em executar essa função numa *thread* separada?