# ProgressBar e BackgroundWorker em C#

Tags: c#, winforms, firebird, progress-bar

Estou criando uma aplicação com `Firebird 2.5` no qual preciso que ela leia um arquivo `.sql` com instruções para popular o banco de dados caso ainda não tenha sido feito estes processo, por ele ser um pouco longo e por não saber ao certo quanto tempo será necessário para concluí-lo e a aplicação não ficar `"não respondendo"` resolvi então adicionar um `ProgressBar` com um `BackgroundWorker`, só que ao adiciona-los estou agora recebendo o seguinte erro durante a execução dos comandos: `Connection must be valid and open`. Agora se eu rodar a aplicação sem o uso do `ProgressBar` e `BackgroundWorker` este erro não ocorre. Este é o código que estou fazendo e a imagem da tela dela funcionando sendo que ele chega a terminar sem dar algum erro. Tive como base este exemplo do DevMedia: http://www.devmedia.com.br/backgrounworker-e-progressbar-exibindo-uma-barra-de-progresso-em-c/32127

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Engebuilder.Library;
using Engebuilder.UI.Windows.General;
using Engebuilder.UI;
using Engebuilder.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

namespace GSD
{
    public partial class FomAux : Engebuilder.UI.Windows.General.DefaultForm
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        public FomAux()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.SetComponents(components);
        }

        private void FomAux_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Interval = 10;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        }

        int contador = 0;

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                contador += 1;

                if (contador >= 5)
                {
                    timer.Enabled = false;
                    contador = 0;

                    backgroundWorkerPopularBanco.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro inesperado: \"" + ex.Message + "\"", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                this.Close();
            }
        }


        private void backgroundWorkerPopularBanco_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string diretorio = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string filePath = Path.Combine(diretorio, "SCRIPT.sql");

                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    string populouBanco = Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.GetDataToString("SELECT CONFIG_SISTEMA.CONF_SIS_POPULOUBANCO FROM CONFIG_SISTEMA");

                    if (populouBanco.Trim().Equals("") || populouBanco.Trim().Equals("N"))
                    {
                        StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF7);
                        string comteudoArq = leitor.ReadToEnd();

                        string[] comando = comteudoArq.Trim().Split(new Char[] { '!' });

                        Int64 contador = 0;

                        foreach (string valor in comando)
                        {
                            contador++;

                            if (!valor.Trim().Equals(""))
                            {
                                Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.ExecuteCommand(valor.Trim());

                                //faz a thread dormir por "p" milissegundos a cada passagem do loop
                                //Thread.Sleep(p);

                                listBox.BeginInvoke(
                                    new Action(() =>
                                    {
                                        listBox.Items.Add("[ " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ] - Processo: " + contador.ToString() + " comcluído.");
                                        listBox.SelectedIndex = listBox.Items.Count - 1;
                                    }
                                ));
                            }
                        }

                        string sqlConfig = "INSERT INTO CONFIG_SISTEMA (CONF_SIS_POPULOUBANCO, CONF_SIS_DATA, CONFI_SIS_LOG) "
                        + " VALUES('S', '" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", ".") + "', NULL)";
                        Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.ExecuteCommand(sqlConfig.Trim());

                        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Configurações Concluídas com Sucesso!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                        if (result.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
                            this.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocoreu um erro Realizar algumas Configurações: \"" + ex.Message + "\"", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorkerPopularBanco_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Caso cancelado...
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // reconfigura a progressbar para o padrao.
                ProgressBarPopularBanco.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
                ProgressBarPopularBanco.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
                ProgressBarPopularBanco.Value = 0;

                //caso a operação seja cancelada, informa ao usuario.
                listBox.Items.Add("[ " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ] - Operação Cancelada pelo Usuário!");

                //limpa a label
                label1.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                //informa ao usuario do acontecimento de algum erro.
                listBox.Items.Add("[ " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ] - Aconteceu um erro durante a execução do processo!");
                // reconfigura a progressbar para o padrao.
                ProgressBarPopularBanco.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
                ProgressBarPopularBanco.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
                ProgressBarPopularBanco.Value = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //informa que a tarefa foi concluida com sucesso.
                listBox.Items.Add("[ " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ] - Processos Concluidos com Sucesso!");
                //Carrega todo progressbar.
                ProgressBarPopularBanco.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
                ProgressBarPopularBanco.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
                ProgressBarPopularBanco.Value = 100;
                label1.Text = ProgressBarPopularBanco.Value.ToString() + "%";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde o erro ocorre?

Comment: Comecei analisar um pouco mais direito os erros que estão ocorrendo aqui e é exatamente o seguinte: 1º ele tá dando este erro: "Connection must be valid and open" pelo verifiquei é como se ele tivesse pedido a conexão com banco, banco esse que infelizmente é o Firebird 2.5. Agora isso só ocorre quando eu executo com ProgressBar e BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Tira o progressbar, coloca uma msg dizendo que irá demorar alguns minutos, trava teclado e mouse, acredito que em C# já exista uma função nativa

Comment: Como foi mostrado uma alternativa no comentário acima, também tentei realizar este procedimento no qual ele realmente bloqueia o mouse e o teclado, porém logo após chamada do mesmo o método que realiza os insert  no banco não executado, bem como qualquer outra função do sistema. Para o bloqueio do mouse e teclado estou seguindo as informações deste post: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51973/bloquear-teclado-e-mouse-ou-impedir-usuario-deixar-janela-em-c#

Comment: Vc ja tentou colocar um breakpoint nessas partes?

Comment: sim @KhaosDoctor com verrifiquei que erro ocorre justamente na execução do comando SQL onde recebo a msg: `Connection must be valid and open` e depois ele para a execução do laço e lança mais uma exceção: `Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.`.

Comment: Tentou um debug para ver qual instância está nula?

Comment: @JoaquimCaetanoTeixeira, qual o comportamento da sua bibilioteca de acesso a dados `Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess`, ela fecha a conexão após a execução, ela permite o uso de transação? Transacionar seria muito bom.

Comment: @RodrigoReis na verdade não posso te afirmar com 100% de certeza, mas acho em 99% ele fecha a conexão a cada execução.

Comment: @JoaquimCaetanoTeixeira E a respeito de transações? Ainda em relação a conexão, existe algum método desta biblioteca que te permite obter a conexão aberta e existe alguma assinatura do método de execução que te permite passar a conexão aberta por referência? Se sim, talvez seja este o caminho...

Answer (score 1):

Caro Joaquim,

Dentre tantas causas para este problema, suponho que se trata de uma aplicação winforms, correto? Tipicamente esses problemas estão relacionadas a execução de threads (o backgroundworker é uma delas...). Perceba que aplicações winforms são *no thread-safe*, ou seja, a execução de um rotina deve começar APENAS se uma outra rotina estiver terminada. Quando se tenta executar rotinas em paralelo mensagens bizarras costumam acontecer, (quando não aconteciam antes da tentativa de usar execuções em paralelo). Pois bem, ainda assim é possìvel executar rotinas em paralelo através do uso das TASK (uma thread com um nível de abstração melhor que as threads de versões anteriores do .NET)
Assim, seguem caminhos para melhor elucidar o seu problema

1. Estude sobre [Task parallel]
2. [Chamadas thread-safe para winforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Possivelmente tente mudar o bloco onde se vê string sqlConfig="...." para dentro de    `this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>{ 
   sqlConfig="...." Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.ExecuteCommand(sqlConfig.Trim());
   };`
4. Dica: Prefira XML do que arquivo TXT.(Passei por diversos problemas com ele...) além do mais, o .NET possui uma vasta gama de métodos para manipulação desses arquivos
5. Veja esse código para melhor entender:

   ```
   #region Thread Status da Conexao
   /// <summary>
   /// Lanca thread para verificação de conexao com banco de dados a cada 5s
   /// <para>Notifica caso conexão caia</para>
   /// </summary>
   private void ThreadConexao()
   {
       Task conexao = new Task(() =>
          {
              bool isconetado = true;
              try
              {
                  while (true)
                  {
                      //Verifica conexao com o banco de dados
                      isconetado = Connect();
                      //Todas as vezes que a rotina é executada
                      //o metodo MethoInvoker é acionado e direciona a chamada ao controle do formulario                           
                      if (isconetado)
                      {
                          this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                          {
                              //Exibir no rodape do form a informacao de conectado
                              label1.Text = "Conectado";
                             //Uma imagem contendo um simbolo de conectado
                              pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.connect_style2;
                          }));

                      }
                      else
                      {
                          this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                          {
                              //Exibir no rodape do form a informacao de desconectado
                              label1.Text = "Desconectado";
                              //Uma imagem contendo um simbolo de desconectado
                              pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.disconnect_style2;

                          }));

                      }
                      //A cada 5 segundos volta a fazer a verificação de conexao com o banco de dados
                      Thread.Sleep(5000);
                  }

              }
              catch (Exception) { }


          });

       conexao.Start();
   }



   #endregion
   ```

Uma imagem de exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]