# Bloquear teclado e mouse em C#, mas mantendo a execução de um método

Tags: c#, winforms, teclado, eventos-do-mouse

Preciso bloquear o uso do teclado e mouse em form enquanto ele irá executar uma determinada função do sistema, no qual estou colocando a chamada do método de bloqueio no evento de `Load` do form, no qual ele realmente estar bloqueando o teclado e o mouse, mas não executa o método que estar logo apos a sua chamada. Segue um código de teste que estou fazendo para testar este procedimento:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GSD
{
    public partial class FormTeste : Form
    {
        public FormTeste()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormTeste_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetHookMouse();
            SetHookTeclado();

            Teste();
        }


        private void Teste()
        {
            //Implementação do método            
        }


        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //Raliza o Bloqueio do Mouse
        //
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Importa as funções que serão usadas
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookExMouse(int idHook,
            LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookExMouse(IntPtr hInstance);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookExMouse(IntPtr idHook, int code, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryMouse(string lpFileName);

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }

        const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14; // Tipo de hook que será usado

        private LowLevelMouseProc hookMouse = hookProcMouse;
        private static IntPtr hhookMouse = IntPtr.Zero;

        public void SetHookMouse()
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibraryMouse("User32");
            hhookMouse = SetWindowsHookExMouse(WH_MOUSE_LL, hookMouse, hInstance, 0); // Instala o hook para a interceptação dos eventos do mouse
        }

        public static void UnHookMouse()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookExMouse(hhookMouse); // Remove o hook instalado
        }

        public static IntPtr hookProcMouse(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            // Se a mensagem recebida for > 0 e o clique do mouse for do botão esquerdo ou direito
            if (code >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam || MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                return (IntPtr)1; // Inibe o clique
            }
            else
                return CallNextHookExMouse(hhookMouse, code, (int)wParam, lParam); // Passa para o próximo evento
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //Raliza o Bloqueio do Teclado
        //
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Importa as funções que serão usadas
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookExTeclado(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookExTeclado(IntPtr hInstance);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookExTeclado(IntPtr idHook, int code, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryTeclado(string lpFileName);

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13; // Tipo de hook que será usado
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;  // Messagem usada para quando uma tecla for pressionada

        private LowLevelKeyboardProc hookTeclado = hookProcTeclado;
        private static IntPtr hhookTeclado = IntPtr.Zero;

        public void SetHookTeclado()
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibraryTeclado("User32");
            hhookTeclado = SetWindowsHookExTeclado(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookTeclado, hInstance, 0); // Instala o hook para o teclado
        }

        public static void UnHookTeclado()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookExTeclado(hhookTeclado);
        }

        public static IntPtr hookProcTeclado(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            { // Quando uma tecla for pressionada
                return (IntPtr)1; // Inibe o funcionamento
            }
            else
                return CallNextHookExTeclado(hhookTeclado, code, (int)wParam, lParam); // Passa para o próximo evento
        }

        private void FormTeste_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            UnHookMouse();

            UnHookTeclado();
        }
    }
}
```

Já tentei usar este código como alternativa mas ele não trava realmente estar realmente bloqueando os evento gerados pelo mouse, ai com um tempo a aplicação começa a aparecer a mensagem de que o sistema parou de responder. Lembrando que todos esses código tiver como base os exemplos que estão disponíveis em: [Bloquear teclado e mouse ou impedir usuario deixar janela em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51973/bloquear-teclado-e-mouse-ou-impedir-usuario-deixar-janela-em-c)

```
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
            public static extern void BlockInput([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool fBlockIt);

  private void FormTeste_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BlockInput(true);

                Teste();
            }
```

Comment: Qual a versão minima do SO que vai rodar? Você precisa bloquear o teclado e mouse e manter a tela ou o que você realmente quer é bloquear a estação de trabalho durante a execução de uma rotina?

Comment: @Intruso seria somente o bloqueio do teclado e mouse somente no form que o estar sendo chamado e mantendo a execução das suas funções, sendo assim logo após o termino deste funções este form será fechado e já que ele é chamado como `ShowDialog` o restante da aplicação também estará ativa. Sobre o sistema operacional utilizado será a partir do windows XP.

Comment: Então, na verdade o que você precisa é evitar o input de dados via teclado/mouse na aplicação (form), correto? Você já tentou bloquear os controles de input do form no lugar de bloquear o teclado/mouse? Tornaria o código muito mais simples.

Comment: @Intruso é justamento o bloqueio somente no form, no qual também já defini o form `Enabled = false;` só que o problema estar que quando esse form é chamado geralmente ele vai demorar uns 3 a 5 minutos sem o usuário pode fazer nada nele, ai se durante esse tempo ele ficar dando algum click ou fazendo qualquer outra coisa a aplicação começa  a aparecer a msg de que a aplicação não estar respondendo.

Comment: Implemente um *background worker* que execute seu processo. Ao invés de bloquear o formulário, cheque o status do *background worker*. Isso fará com que sua aplicação continue responsiva, ao mesmo tempo que você pode emitir uma mensagem que o processo ainda está sendo executado - ou até mesmo exibir um percentual de execução.

Comment: @Ibotinelly na verdade isso foi a 1ª coisa que comecei a fazer, porém, tiver alguns problemas como estar no post: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108392/progressbar-e-backgroundworker-em-c ai como alternativa vim para o bloqueio do mouse e teclado que não estar dando certo, agora não sei mais posso fazer como alternativa. Pois o que preciso é que durante um determinado tempo, tempo esse que não tem como eu saber ao certo o quanto será necessário para a leitura de arquivo sql e execução dos mesmos para população do banco e durante esse período o usuário não poder fazer nada na aplicação.

Comment: Veja se minha resposta ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Separe a thread de execução ta tela (do form) da thread de execução do seu método.** O aplicativo trava e fica como se não estivesse respondendo porque por padrão a thread do form é usada para rodar os eventos (metodos) do seu form. Então, ou ele atualiza ou executa, sacou?

Para resolver, você pode simplesmente colocar o seu método em uma outra thread e bloquear os controles do form até a thread terminar. Existem varias formas de fazer isso, mas, cada uma tem algumas implicações.

**Use um delegate para um metodo que é executado ao terminar a thread.** Como você deve saber, um delegate é um "ponteiro" para um metodo e pode ser chamado em execuções orientadas a eventos. Geralmente, quando você clica em um botâo e declara um metodo, quando você olha as propriedades, verifica que aquele metodo esta "atribuido" ao evento 'on_click' do button. Na verdade, você tem um delegate apontando para seu metodo e esse delegate é chamado quando alguem clica.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    int _count;

    void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadWorker worker = new ThreadWorker(HandleThreadDone);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(worker.Run);
        thread1.Start();

        _count = 1;
    }

    void HandleThreadDone()
    {
        // As before - just a simple example
        if (_count == 1)
        {
            ThreadWorker worker = new ThreadWorker();

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(worker.Run);
            thread2.Start(HandleThreadDone);

            _count++;
        }
    }

    class ThreadWorker
    {
        // Switch to your favourite Action<T> or Func<T>
        public void Run(object state)
        {
            // Do a task

            Action completeAction = (Action)state;
            completeAction.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

**Use um evento.** Você pode disparar um evento ao finalizar o trabalho de uma tread (lembre da explicação acima). Veja o exemplo:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    int _count;

    void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadWorker worker = new ThreadWorker();
        worker.ThreadDone += HandleThreadDone;

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(worker.Run);
        thread1.Start();

        _count = 1;
    }

    void HandleThreadDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // You should get the idea this is just an example
        if (_count == 1)
        {
            ThreadWorker worker = new ThreadWorker();
            worker.ThreadDone += HandleThreadDone;

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(worker.Run);
            thread2.Start();

            _count++;
        }
    }

    class ThreadWorker
    {
        public event EventHandler ThreadDone;

        public void Run()
        {
            // Do a task

            if (ThreadDone != null)
                ThreadDone(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

As diferenças são sutis, mas, você deve poder entender o conceito. No seu caso em particular, você precisará de mais 2 metodos, um para bloquear os controles do form e outro para habilitar os controles. No estado inicial, você dispara sua task e bloqueia os controles e ao finalizar a thread, executa o metodo para desbloquear.

A tela ficará atualizada (bloqueada), mas, não exibirá mais a mensagem de não respondendo.

Comment: para ser sincero não entendi muito não, se possível você poderia explicar um pouco mais como é a lógica de funcionamento da class **ThreadWorker** e o método **Rum**. Desde já grato!